# \subtitle in fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

KOMA class allows titles (`\title{}`) and subtitles (`\subtitle{}`). I want to make a header that automatically inserts both.

In the standard article class the title can be achieved using the command `\runtitle`:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{} %clear header footer
    \fancyhead[L]{\today} 
    \fancyhead[R]{\runtitle}
```

but is there a similar `\subtitle` command? Ideally:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{} %clear header footer
    \fancyhead[L]{\today} 
    \fancyhead[C]{\runtitle}
    \fancyhead[R]{\runsubtitle}
```

Comment: You can usually put almost anything you want in the fancyhead. Try something like this: In the Preamble, `\def\subtitle#1{\def\mysubtitle{#1}}` then `\subtitle{Your Subtitle}` then in the fancyhdr portion, `\fancyhead[R]{\mysubtitle}`. You can also use code to style it, perhaps if you want italics or small caps.

Comment: But how does this automatically pull from the content in KOMA's `\subtitle{}` command?

Comment: also this straight up does not work

Comment: `fancyhdr` and `koma-script` are incompatible. Better use `scrlayer-scrpage` for your headers and footers.

Comment: Sorry, I was not making a KOMA-specific comment. Just general purpose. Works for me, but I am using an entirely different setup, which does not already have a `\subtitle{}` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the KOMA-script package `scrlayer-scrpage`. I guess the header will get pretty crowded that way.

[image: invictusKomaHeader]

```
\documentclass[headinclude]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\ihead{\today}
\makeatletter
\chead{\@title}
\ohead{\@subtitle}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\title{The Wombats Journey}
\subtitle{Spring}
\author{Carl Capybara}
\maketitle
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```